# How do I know if logistic linearity assumption is met based on graphs?

Tags: r, logistic, classification, linear

[image]

How do I know if my logistic model's numeric variables violate the linearity assumption on the log(target variable)?

I am using the code found at [THIS LINK](http://www.sthda.com/english/articles/36-classification-methods-essentials/148-logistic-regression-assumptions-and-diagnostics-in-r/). They graphed on the same data but I, personally, only used my training data.

> The variable age and pedigree is not linear and might need some transformations.

I'm ready to do so, but I'd first like to know why it is that they consider `DiabetesPedigreeFunction` & `age` as non-linear? What shape would you say qualifies the variable as linear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a smoothing spline approach (proposed by @AdamO) in a higher-dimensional context as well.  The conditioning plots are fine if there are only three independent variables, but in a situation like the one you propose several different conditioning plots would be required and it would be difficult to derive much actionable intelligence from them. Instead, you could use a generalized additive model (GAM) to model flexible non-linearity on the link scale.  Here's an example using the `mgcv` package in R.

First, load the data, specify the independent variables and make the formulas for the models.  Note that wrapping a variable in `s()` changes the form from linear to (potentially) non-linear by using a smoothing spline to estimate the relationship with `y`.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(broom)
library(mgcv)

data("PimaIndiansDiabetes2", package = "mlbench")
PimaIndiansDiabetes2 <- na.omit(PimaIndiansDiabetes2)
# Fit the logistic regression model

ivs <- c("pregnant", "glucose", "pressure", "triceps", "insulin", "mass", "pedigree", "age")
forms <- sapply(ivs, function(x)
  reformulate(ifelse(ivs == x, paste0("s(", ivs, ")"), ivs), 
              "diabetes"))
```

Next, we can estimate the null model where all effects are linear.

```r
mod.null <- gam(diabetes ~ pregnant + glucose + pressure + triceps + 
                 insulin + mass + pedigree + age, 
               data = PimaIndiansDiabetes2, 
               family = binomial)
```

We could then get the AIC differences of each model to the null model.

```r
smods <- lapply(forms, function(x)gam(x, data=PimaIndiansDiabetes2, family=binomial))

sort(sapply(smods, AIC) - AIC(mod.null))
#>           age       insulin          mass      pedigree       triceps 
#> -6.9494706510 -4.1703198157 -2.1917412788 -0.4979687138  0.0001220039 
#>      pressure       glucose      pregnant 
#>  0.0001247168  0.0001520076  0.0001769288
```

Here, non-linear terms in `age`, `insulin`, `mass` and `pedigree` are improvements over the null model, though modeling non-linearity in `pedigree` doesn't seem to improve the model much. We could then start with the biggest improvement and then add in other non-linear trends as they are necessary.  We cannot just automatically add non-linear trends for `age`, `insulin` and `mass` because they modeling unobserved non-linearity for one variable may change the way other variables relate to `y`.  So, we start with the `age` variable.

```r
m1 <- gam(diabetes ~ pregnant + glucose + pressure + triceps + 
            insulin + mass + pedigree + s(age), 
          data = PimaIndiansDiabetes2, 
          family = binomial)

anova(mod.null, m1, test='Chisq')
#> Analysis of Deviance Table
#> 
#> Model 1: diabetes ~ pregnant + glucose + pressure + triceps + insulin + 
#>     mass + pedigree + age
#> Model 2: diabetes ~ pregnant + glucose + pressure + triceps + insulin + 
#>     mass + pedigree + s(age)
#>   Resid. Df Resid. Dev     Df Deviance Pr(>Chi)  
#> 1    383.00     344.02                           
#> 2    379.12     331.30 3.8846   12.725  0.01158 *
#> ---
#> Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1
```

We see from above that allowing a non-linear functional form for `age` produces a significantly better model.  Moving on, we will test the linearity of the effect of `insulin`.  One important caveat here is that we need to ensure that the only thing changing across the two models is the functional form for `insulin`.  As such, we must hold fixed what would otherwise be a potentially changing non-linear relationship between `age` and `y`.  To do this, we specify the degrees of freedom the relationship will use (`k` is the degrees of freedom + 1) and use `fx=TRUE` in the call to `s()`. This will ensure that the non-linearity in `age`  will be of the same form across the two models.

```r
summary(m1)
#> 
#> Family: binomial 
#> Link function: logit 
#> 
#> Formula:
#> diabetes ~ pregnant + glucose + pressure + triceps + insulin + 
#>     mass + pedigree + s(age)
#> 
#> Parametric coefficients:
#>               Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
#> (Intercept) -8.3908109  1.2235167  -6.858 6.99e-12 ***
#> pregnant     0.0402072  0.0571396   0.704   0.4816    
#> glucose      0.0375236  0.0058529   6.411 1.44e-10 ***
#> pressure    -0.0042853  0.0119421  -0.359   0.7197    
#> triceps      0.0099064  0.0173894   0.570   0.5689    
#> insulin     -0.0003452  0.0013406  -0.257   0.7968    
#> mass         0.0627002  0.0274747   2.282   0.0225 *  
#> pedigree     1.0854046  0.4313465   2.516   0.0119 *  
#> ---
#> Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1
#> 
#> Approximate significance of smooth terms:
#>          edf Ref.df Chi.sq p-value  
#> s(age) 3.888  4.885  13.12  0.0215 *
#> ---
#> Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1
#> 
#> R-sq.(adj) =  0.375   Deviance explained = 33.5%
#> UBRE = -0.094205  Scale est. = 1         n = 392

m1f <- gam(diabetes ~ pregnant + glucose + pressure + triceps + 
            insulin + mass + pedigree + s(age, k=5, fx=TRUE), 
          data = PimaIndiansDiabetes2, 
          family = binomial)
m2 <- gam(diabetes ~ pregnant + glucose + pressure + triceps + 
             s(insulin) + mass + pedigree + s(age, k=5, fx=TRUE), 
           data = PimaIndiansDiabetes2, 
           family = binomial)

anova(m1f, m2, test='Chisq')
#> Analysis of Deviance Table
#> 
#> Model 1: diabetes ~ pregnant + glucose + pressure + triceps + insulin + 
#>     mass + pedigree + s(age, k = 5, fx = TRUE)
#> Model 2: diabetes ~ pregnant + glucose + pressure + triceps + s(insulin) + 
#>     mass + pedigree + s(age, k = 5, fx = TRUE)
#>   Resid. Df Resid. Dev     Df Deviance Pr(>Chi)  
#> 1    380.00     331.61                           
#> 2    372.22     313.97 7.7841   17.646  0.02141 *
#> ---
#> Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1
```

Note here that the non-linearity in `insulin` is also significant - indicating that the model significantly improves when the functional form of the `insulin` variable is made more flexible.  Following the same process as above, we can test for non-linearity in `mass`.

```r
summary(m2)
#> 
#> Family: binomial 
#> Link function: logit 
#> 
#> Formula:
#> diabetes ~ pregnant + glucose + pressure + triceps + s(insulin) + 
#>     mass + pedigree + s(age, k = 5, fx = TRUE)
#> 
#> Parametric coefficients:
#>              Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
#> (Intercept) -8.599060   1.381969  -6.222 4.90e-10 ***
#> pregnant     0.057864   0.059608   0.971  0.33168    
#> glucose      0.034614   0.006207   5.577 2.45e-08 ***
#> pressure    -0.001621   0.012620  -0.128  0.89782    
#> triceps      0.007756   0.018136   0.428  0.66889    
#> mass         0.065503   0.029002   2.259  0.02391 *  
#> pedigree     1.229714   0.446129   2.756  0.00584 ** 
#> ---
#> Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1
#> 
#> Approximate significance of smooth terms:
#>            edf Ref.df Chi.sq p-value  
#> s(insulin) 8.1  8.784  13.13   0.106  
#> s(age)     4.0  4.000  11.35   0.023 *
#> ---
#> Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1
#> 
#> R-sq.(adj) =  0.399   Deviance explained =   37%
#> UBRE = -0.10161  Scale est. = 1         n = 392

m2f <- gam(diabetes ~ pregnant + glucose + pressure + triceps + 
            s(insulin, k=9, fx=TRUE) + mass + pedigree + s(age, k=5, fx=TRUE), 
          data = PimaIndiansDiabetes2, 
          family = binomial)

m3 <- gam(diabetes ~ pregnant + glucose + pressure + triceps + 
             s(insulin, k=9, fx=TRUE) + s(mass) + pedigree + s(age, k=5, fx=TRUE), 
           data = PimaIndiansDiabetes2, 
           family = binomial)

anova(m2f, m3, test='Chisq')
#> Analysis of Deviance Table
#> 
#> Model 1: diabetes ~ pregnant + glucose + pressure + triceps + s(insulin, 
#>     k = 9, fx = TRUE) + mass + pedigree + s(age, k = 5, fx = TRUE)
#> Model 2: diabetes ~ pregnant + glucose + pressure + triceps + s(insulin, 
#>     k = 9, fx = TRUE) + s(mass) + pedigree + s(age, k = 5, fx = TRUE)
#>   Resid. Df Resid. Dev     Df Deviance Pr(>Chi)
#> 1    373.00     315.00                         
#> 2    370.43     310.64 2.5729   4.3605   0.1735
```

Here, the difference is not statistically significant - indicating that the relationship is not significantly improved when non-linearity is allowed.  Retaining the linear form (on the link scale) is appropriate. We can move on and do the same for `pedigree`.

```r
m4 <- gam(diabetes ~ pregnant + glucose + pressure + triceps + 
            s(insulin, k=9, fx=TRUE) + mass + s(pedigree) + s(age, k=5, fx=TRUE), 
          data = PimaIndiansDiabetes2, 
          family = binomial)

anova(m2f, m4, test='Chisq')
#> Analysis of Deviance Table
#> 
#> Model 1: diabetes ~ pregnant + glucose + pressure + triceps + s(insulin, 
#>     k = 9, fx = TRUE) + mass + pedigree + s(age, k = 5, fx = TRUE)
#> Model 2: diabetes ~ pregnant + glucose + pressure + triceps + s(insulin, 
#>     k = 9, fx = TRUE) + mass + s(pedigree) + s(age, k = 5, fx = TRUE)
#>   Resid. Df Resid. Dev         Df   Deviance Pr(>Chi)   
#> 1       373        315                                  
#> 2       373        315 0.00023655 0.00013726 0.001065 **
#> ---
#> Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1
```

This is an interesting case because the result is significant, but as you can see the difference in residual degrees of freedom is about 0.0002 - indicating a model that is very nearly linear.  Despite a significant result here, the linear relationship (on the link scale) should be retained.  We can then estimate, summarize and plot the final model.

```r
mod.final <- gam(diabetes ~ pregnant + glucose + pressure + triceps + 
                   s(insulin) + mass + pedigree + s(age), 
                 data = PimaIndiansDiabetes2, 
                 family = binomial)

summary(mod.final)
#> 
#> Family: binomial 
#> Link function: logit 
#> 
#> Formula:
#> diabetes ~ pregnant + glucose + pressure + triceps + s(insulin) + 
#>     mass + pedigree + s(age)
#> 
#> Parametric coefficients:
#>               Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
#> (Intercept) -8.7741665  1.3915436  -6.305 2.88e-10 ***
#> pregnant     0.0573195  0.0594034   0.965  0.33459    
#> glucose      0.0357828  0.0061995   5.772 7.84e-09 ***
#> pressure    -0.0007469  0.0126257  -0.059  0.95283    
#> triceps      0.0069614  0.0180179   0.386  0.69923    
#> mass         0.0659178  0.0290142   2.272  0.02309 *  
#> pedigree     1.3001933  0.4485428   2.899  0.00375 ** 
#> ---
#> Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1
#> 
#> Approximate significance of smooth terms:
#>              edf Ref.df Chi.sq p-value  
#> s(insulin) 8.287  8.857  13.82  0.0921 .
#> s(age)     4.409  5.429  11.48  0.0554 .
#> ---
#> Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1
#> 
#> R-sq.(adj) =  0.406   Deviance explained = 37.4%
#> UBRE = -0.10374  Scale est. = 1         n = 392

par(mfrow=c(1,2))
plot(mod.final, select=1)
plot(mod.final, select=2)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-12-29 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Looking at the rug plots, you may want to re-evaluate whether these non-linear relationships are the potential result of some outliers (i.e., more regression diagnostics), but a procedure like this could provide more concrete advice about the appropriate functional forms of variables.

Comment: By way of shameless self-promotion, I wrote a book that discusses this idea - [_Presenting Statistical Results Effectively_, by Sage](https://us.sagepub.com/en-us/nam/presenting-statistical-results-effectively/book240604), see pp. 232-237 for a discussion of this idea.

Comment: `Glucose` and `Insulin` are highly correlated. In my analysis, I dropped `Insulin` due to this information. Given that you've downloaded and inspected the data, do you see anything wrong with this step I took?

Comment: @Antonio `glucose` and `insulin` are correlated at 0.58 and their VIFs are 1/67 and 1.56, respectively.  I probably wouldn't remove a variable based on those numbers.  In fact the highest VIF is for `age` at 2.13 - still probably not high enough to merit removing it. I would look at how influential the `insulin` values over 600 and `age` over 60 are.

Comment: I dropped `Insulin` due to the higher number of NA values, as well (48%), thinking that the lack of variance provided from the NA values impacts models on unseen data. Is it wise to still include it or does it come down to choice?

Comment: It is really impossible to say for certain whether dropping `Insulin` is a good idea or not.  This is a bigger question you should ask (or search for other answers) - it probably shouldn't be answered in the comment of this question.

Answer (score 1):

You're accidentally asking more than one question. The first is whether the trend relating a continuous exposure and a binary outcome. One possible way to inspect such a trend is to create a non-parametric smoothing function, such as a smoothing spline.

```
x <- seq(-3, 3, by=0.1)
y <- rbinom(length(x), 1, plogis(-2 + 1*x))
plot(x,y)
lines(smooth.spline(x=x, y=y), col='red')
lines(x, predict(glm(y ~ x, family=binomial), type='response'), col='blue')
```

[image: ![enter image description here]

You can also plot the GLM object itself, and pay particular attention to the plot of Pearson residuals versus fitted. Despite the infamous appearance, you can expect that the mean should be 0 and the variance should be constant across all predicted values. They give you a Loess smooth line to deal with this problem.

[image]

Departures from this could signify a misspecified logistic model.

The second question is whether the multivariate association holds, that is controlling for other predictors, U, V, W, does the X,Y relationship meet certain criteria (similarly, controlling for X,V,W does the U,Y  relationship ... and so on...). For some reason, people seem to think that plotting the bivariate associations - like you've shown here - does something. Maybe, but dimensionality is complicated that way. A more powerful tool to inspect these relations is a coplot.

```
w <- abs(seq(-3, 3, by=0.1))
y2 <- rbinom(length(x), 1, plogis(-0.3 + 1 * x - 0.2*w))
mypanel <- function(x, y, ...) panel.smooth(x=x, y=y, span=1/2, ...)
coplot(y ~ x | w, panel=mypanel)
```

[image]

Notice what a terrible smoother LOESS is compared to a smoothing spline for binary response - this is because LOESS excludes outliers. Anyway, coplots work well for multivariate data because you expect the plots to be identical when there is no interaction between covariates. And, as above, you expect the smoother to show a nice logistic trend line relating the exposure to response.